# Is data recovery theoretically possible for this sort of crack?

Tags: file-recovery, microsd

Is data recovery possible for this sort of crack?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My micro sd card was broken into two pieces and got flushed, is there any chance it can get recovered by someone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129488/my-micro-sd-card-was-broken-into-two-pieces-and-got-flushed-is-there-any-chance)

Answer (score 4):

No sorry. You can be 'virtually' 100% certain this broke the NAND. As long as the NAND is intact there's a chance but it would still be a major undertaking.

Now assume data is vital, and you find a lab that even sees a remote chance to pull it off, chance of success would be so uncertain and so much effort would go into this, price will be astronomical or the lab will require a considerable attempt fee but probably both.

[image]

To give an idea.. See those stacked dies, connected by microscopic bondwires. Anything broken in there is beyond repair.

To be absolutely certain first step would actually require an x-ray of your microSD card and then determine location and dimensions of the NAND but I am willing to bet money on this being a mission impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I sent the picture to DriveSavers who said “we have new technology that may make data recovery possible, even for a break like this.” Is this still reliant on the NAND chip being intact or is there a remote possibility of retrieval even if the NAND chip is affected?

Comment: @Jush42355, SD cards are manufactured by 7nm process (by 2019 years). So if the chip is broken they should map two peaces with preciseness of these 7 nm. Which is (IMHO) practically impossible.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I read online that data can be retrieved from just one of the chip pieces as well?

Comment: @Jush42355, even if they read the chip then it's need to reconstruct filesystem, directories (if any) and files. So my personal estimation is they may recover 1 file from 1000 (optimistic) :(

Comment: @Jush42355, call their bluff and explain this is their chance to proof this capability to the World - of course no charge for you.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, it's worse than that. If they manage to dump chip you basically have an non error corrected, scrambled 'binary blob' that is nowhere close to a file system yet. With some 'luck' ECC algorithm isn't even supported yet.